# How to handle EventProcessorClient error callback "Attempting to renew all of the processor's partition ownership in the storage service."?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I implemented a service that uses the EventProcessorClient component to process events from an Azure EventHub.
The error callback

```
private Task OnErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)...
```

is executed many times, with

- args.Operation set to "Executing a load balancing cycle."
- args.Exception to "Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventHubsException(GeneralError): Attempting to renew all of the processor's partition ownership in the storage service."

Is it a proper error or just a notification that is safe to ignore?

Comment: [EventProcessorClient stuck in load balancing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12088), [Lease management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host#lease-management) and [Clarifying event hub errors related to: Renewing Lease, Closing Event Processor, Checking Leases, Stealing Lease](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/7162)

Comment: Thx DeepDave, the only difference in my case is that events are processed. I assume load balancing from time to time would be normal, so it's safe to ignore.

Comment: Can you define "many times"?    Seeing occasional errors is normal and often due to transient network issues.   Seeing a recurring pattern or frequent errors may indicate a problem.   Without additional context, it's tough to say more.   The processor section of the troubleshooting guide may be helpful: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#troubleshoot-event-processor-issues